# Sum of independent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be independent Bernoulli r.v. such that $X_i \sim Ber(q_i)$ with $0 < q_i \leq 1/n$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $q_i = q$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, then $X_1, X_2, ...$ are i.i.d. and, for any $m \geq 1$, we can easily show that
$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2m} X_i \geq 1\right) \leq 2 P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i \geq 1\right).$$

I was wondering, is it true that if $X_i$'s are independent but not necessarily identically distributed, then we also have
$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2m} X_i \geq 1\right) \leq M P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i \geq 1\right)$$
for some constant $M>0$?

Comment: What happens if $q_1$ is very small but $q_2$ is almost $1$?

Comment: It doesn't have to be true then. I guess if you take $q_1 = 1/m$ and $q_2 = 1 - 1/m$ then it will not be true if you start taking larger and larger $m$, i.e. as $m \rightarrow \infty$. But what about when $q_i$ are not the same but vary only very little?